# Current location of user with FAB on google maps in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create the blue geolocation icon that appears on google maps and that can center the user when clicked on. I have created the permission to ask the user for location already to use google maps, but how can I get their current location ? Is there a way to do it with google maps in compose or is it not yet implemented as a feature?

[image]

Comment: You can checkout this repository, https://github.com/sahalnazar/location-fetch-in-jetpack-compose

Comment: I checked out the repo but it only provided me with coordinates. You got any suggestion to how I can combine that with a floatingactionbutton to display user location ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this and I think after that you are good to go!

```
 val cameraPositionState= rememberCameraPositionState()

GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    cameraPositionState=cameraPositionState,
    properties = MapProperties(isMyLocationEnabled = true)
)
```